# Ubuntu one changes 'Date modified' to time and date of sync

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm wondering why ubuntu one changes the date of the synced files. Instead of leaving the actual date and time of modification it updates the time and date to the sync time. So, e.g., if I change and save a file today at july 26 2 pm and I go home and sync my home-pc with u1 tomorrow at 10 the 'Date modified' of that file will reflect the syncdate which might be July 27, 10am.

I don't like that behavior and I don't understand if this is a bug or if that is actually intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Ubuntu One documentation](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-are-file-modified-dates-showing-the-date-the-file-was-last-synchronized/), it appears that this is intentional:

> Ubuntu One does not keep track of the metadata like file modified
>   dates, therefore the file system will see that newly synchronized
>   files have a last modified date of the synchronization, not when the
>   content of the file was last modified.

It seems silly to me too though...

Comment: absolutely silly. Especially if you try finding files according to the date you worked on them - and you fail because the date reflects something very different...

Comment: I can see if they wouldn't want some permissions to be synced (different users on different systems), but in my opinion the dates should be.